# How to evaluate in bash a sum of numbers

Tags: bash, awk

I have a naive bash question.

```
export A=`wc file.txt` 
export B=`echo $A[1] - 1 | bc`
```

The problem is that I cannot evaluate the first element in $A. 
I could do it with awk

```
echo $A | awk '{print $1}'
```

But it does not work if I insert it in the previous equation.

Maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: As a side note, if you just want the number of lines and not the file name, you can say `wc -l < file.txt`.

Comment: Bash doesn't automatically split strings into fields, this obviously won't work.You could do something like `A=($(wc test));echo ${A[0]}` though. Although as fedorqui mentioned it would be best to just use `wc -l`

Comment: @JID good explanation. Note I also mentioned `<`, to prevent having the file name in the output

Comment: @fedorqui yep sorry :)

Comment: You would never do what you are currently attempting in real code so if we help you to implement that you may miss the opportunity to learn the correct way to do whatever it is you actually need to do. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and consider posting a question about what you want to do rather than how to implement this specific solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the variable `$A` to the output of `wc`. Since you show `$A[1]` it looks like you want the 2nd value, that is, the number of words, but then you use `$1` in awk, so I think you want number of lines, `-l` parameter in `wc`.

So from now on I am supposing you want to use lines. If not, just change the solution with `-l` instead of `-w`.

The thing is that `wc file` outputs many parameters. If you specify `-w` or `-l`, it gets its value together with the file name. But if you do indirection like `wc -l < file.txt`, you just get the number of lines, so you don't have to clean the output.

This way, you can do:

```
a=$(wc -l < file.txt)
b=$(echo "$a" -1 | bc)
```

All together, you may want to use this directly, without the need to store the intermediate value:

```
b=$(echo "$(wc -l <file.txt)" -1 | bc)
```

Or if you want to use `awk`, you can say:

```
awk -v lines="$(wc -l < file.txt)" 'BEGIN {print lines-1}'
```

Or even use `$(( ))` to perform calculations, as [suggested by JID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939948/how-to-evaluate-in-bash-a-sum-of-numbers/29940574?noredirect=1#comment48002141_29940574):

```
b=$(($(wc -l <file.txt) - 1 ))
```

or

```
((b=$(wc -l <file.txt)-1))
```

Comment: If its an integer you could also do `b=$(($(wc -l <file.txt) - 1 ))` or `((b=$(wc -l <test)-1))`

Comment: Cool! Since output of `wc` is always an integer (sounds logic), I will add this one also to the set of solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Say, this one can be good:

```
   export A=$(wc < file.txt)
   export B=$(echo "$(echo $A | cut -d' ' -f1) - 1" | bc)
```

or even

```
export B=$(echo "$(wc < file.txt | cut -d' ' -f1) - 1" | bc)
```

if you are not going to use 'wc' result further.

The 'wc' command prints newline, word and byte counter (see man page),
which are space-separated, so cut is good enough here.

If you need 'wc' result as an array, you need to split it and to write into a pre-declared 'A' array manually.

Comment: You may as well use `wc -l` rather than piping to `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

I always like using `read` to read input if I can.

```
$ read a _ < <(wc -l /path/to/file)
$ b=$((a - 1))
```

In this case `$_` is a throw-away variable containing the filename.  Input redirection as others have suggested is also a perfectly viable option.

Note that you only need to *export* variables if you intend to use them in the environments called from within your shell.